# networkx random graph, bipartite sets

Tags: graph, networkx, bipartite

I am trying to create a Uniform Random Intersection graph using networkx.  The function uniform_random_intersection_graph(n,m,p), creates such a graph with n the nodes of the first bipartite set and m the nodes of the second bipartite set, according to the documentation.

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.uniform_random_intersection_graph(10,3,0.2)
```

However when i use

```
G.nodes()
```

only the set of the n nodes are displayed and

`G.nodes.data()`

returns

```
[(0, {'bipartite': 0}), (1, {'bipartite': 0}), (2, {'bipartite': 0}), (3, {'bipartite': 0}), (4, {'bipartite': 0}), (5, {'bipartite': 0}), (6, {'bipartite': 0}), (7, {'bipartite': 0}), (8, {'bipartite': 0}), (9, {'bipartite': 0})]
```

How can I traverse the nodes of the second bipartite set (m) ?

Comment: It seems like you want a random bipartite graph rather than a random intersection graph.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by a "random intersection graph"?  There's a problem here that you're not expecting the output you're getting, which suggests to me that you have a different idea of what a random intersection graph should be from what networkx thinks.

Comment: A node u from the set N has edge to the node v of the M set. A node w from the set N has edge to the node v of the M set. Then there is an edge (u,w)

Comment: So you have your original bipartite graph with a set N and a set M.  You've now created your new graph with the `(u,w)` style edges.  The `M` set does not appear in your new graph.  IN your example, `v` would not exist in the final graph.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're trying to create an intersection graph?  I think you might be trying to create a random bipartite graph with 10 nodes in one set and 3 in the other, connected with probability 0.2  If so, you want

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.bipartite.random_graph(10,3,0.2)
```

The graph that you are creating starts as a bipartite graph, but then it takes the first set of nodes and joins a pair of nodes if they share a neighbor in the bipartite graph.  So it is not a bipartite graph, and it does not have the second set of nodes.  Check out `G.edges()` to see a bit more what's going on.

Comment: Yes,what i want is a random intersection graph G(n,m,p). I get it but when i use G.nodes(), only the nodes of the set n (10 nodes) are displayed, and not any nodes of the set m.  Also, it happens the same when i use G.draw() and only the 10 nodes of the n set are shown

Comment: I figured out hat 'm' set are attributes and not nodes. How can I list them ?

Comment: You are looking for `print(G.nodes(data=True))` or `print(G.nodes(data='bipartite'))`, but they are all in the same (bipartite=0), because the code project the bipartite random graph, see the source of the uniform_random_intersection

Comment: Ok, i have edited the uniform_random_intersection function in order to return the m set as well.